# Why does webpack includes a Buffer polyfill by default?

Tags: webpack

Webpack docs say that a polyfill for `Buffer` is included by default (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node-buffer).

1. Why is it so?
2. Does it make the bundle larger for people who do not need to use `Buffer`?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason but it seems that in Webpack 5 this is no longer true. See https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#test-webpack-5-compatibility

Comment: You are reading documentation specifically aimed at Node environment. You don't usually worry about bundle sizes as the intented code might not run in browser at all.

However as @Mišo mentioned, v5 of Webpack actually dropped bunch of built-in polyfills for the purpose of reducing bundle sizes. Now you have to explcitly opt-in for polyfills.